# Trouble with Python3 imports

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

This question was asked a lots of times but none of the solutions seem to help in my case.

I have a directory structure like this

```
my_project/
    main.py
    bootstrap/
        __init__.py
        boot.py
    consumer/
        __init__.py
        main.py
```

Being at the toplevel directory (`myproject`) and executing `python3 consumer/main.py` throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "consumer/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from bootstrap.boot import MyClass
ImportError: No module named 'bootstrap'
```

Weird thing is that importing that module using the interpreter works as expected. Running the code from PyCharm also works fine.

I've tried importing with "full path" e.g. `from my_project.bootstrap.boot import MyClass` which fails with the same `ImportError`. I have also tried using relative imports e.g. `from .bootstrap.boot import MyClass` which also failed with `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`

One hack that fixes this is when I add `export PYTHONPATH="/root/my_project"` at the bottom of virtualenv `activate` script

Comment: Have you tried "from my_project.bootstrap import MyClass" ?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the question, thank you.

Comment: try adding an `__init__.py` to the `my_project/` directory, see if that helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because module search path only includes the current directory, and not its parents; and since your other module is not in the `PYTHONPATH` it isn't available to import.

You can find this out yourself by printing `sys.path` in your script.

I created a directory `t` with the following:

```
$ tree
.
├── a.py
├── bar
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── world.py
└── foo
    ├── hello.py
    └── __init__.py

2 directories, 5 files
```

Here is the source of `hello.py`:

```
$ cat foo/hello.py
import sys
print("I am in {}".format(__file__))
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)

from bar.world import var
print(var)
```

Now watch what happens, when I execute `foo/hello.py` and try to import something from `bar/world.py`;

```
$ python foo/hello.py
I am in foo/hello.py
/home/burhan/t/foo
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/burhan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo/hello.py", line 6, in <module>
    from bar.world import var
ImportError: No module named bar.world
```

You can tell from the paths printed that only the system-wide Python library paths, and the current directory of the script is listed. This is why it cannot find `bar.world`.

To fix this issue, you can adjust the PYTHONPATH or use relative imports; for example:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=../t python foo/hello.py
I am in foo/hello.py
/home/burhan/t/foo
/home/burhan/t
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/home/burhan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
42
```

You notice here I am manually overriding the `PYTHONTPATH` and adding the common parent of the scripts (`42` is coming from bar/world).

To fix this using relative imports, you first have a to create a package in the top most directory, otherwise you'll get the famous `Attempted relative import in non-package` error; for more on this and details on how Python 3 importing works, have a look at: [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: would you mind going through how to create the top level as a package?